# Does Taldane (Common) in Golarion have non-gendered pronouns?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, languages, golarion

I have an Iruxi (lizardfolk) monk who would consider it rude to ask about someone's gender in normal discussion -- unlike those mammals, they just don't obsess about the dangly bits on other people's bodies.  How they communicate with other people, however, would depend heavily on the way that the Taldane (Common) language handles gender.  Is there any documentation from Paizo regarding the Inner Sea setting that would indicate how it works?  AFAICT, I would need to choose between:

1. a language that has no gendered pronouns or articles, in which case it wouldn't ever come up in conversation;
2. a language with both gendered and non-gendered pronouns and articles, in which case it might be noticed in conversation but not matter much;
3. a language like Spanish, where everything is gendered, and the need to choose one option over another could cause misunderstandings.

To clarify, I am not asking what language *I* would use -- I assume the table speaks whatever language its players are most comfortable using.  This is an RP question about the in-game characteristics of the language that the *character* would speak.

Comment: It could be worth noting that while Taldane is the common language of the Inner Sea region, other locations in Golarion have different common languages (such as Mwangi in the Mwangi Expanse, or Tien in Tian Xia).

Comment: I agree that the answer for these other regions' common tongues is also an interesting one, though I was looking for the answer as it regards the Inner Sea.  Is there a tag I should have added for that?

Comment: Are there any real life languages like your 2nd option? Or do you consider "it" as non-gendered?

Comment: Huh, this is an interesting one. My first reaction was "English" (as an English speaker), followed by "whatever your table's primary language is" on further thought. But now I'm not sure... What *do* non-English tables generally play Common as? English? Latin? French? The local dialect?

Comment: @András, I would say that "it" is non-gendered, but it is not suitable for describing persons.  That's why I didn't mention "English" for option #2 -- we typically end up using "they", which confuses people who don't understand it's use for single individuals.

Comment: updated my question to clarify in response to the question from @AceCalhoon, which was not the intended direction of my post.

Comment: @papidave, this is my point, if you have more than the 2 gendered pronoun, the rest is usually not applicable to people.

Comment: "People" on Golarion, I would argue, doesn't mean the same thing as it does on earth.  Leshies and constructs can be "people" in the Inner Sea region; how would you gender *them*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### There is no official language analogues for Golarion

The [Inner Sea World Guide](https://paizo.com/products/btpy8ief) and [Pathfinder Wiki](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Human_languages_of_Golarion#cite_note-1) seem to me the best sources of knowledge on this matter, and neither comment on parallels in real world languages.

**That being the case, your group should talk about it and decide which method will provide the most entertainment and least stress given your character choice.**

If you are looking for [best guesses](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r9p8?Golarion-Language-to-Earth-Language-Translations), I have most commonly seen Taldane equated to British English (with Andoran sometimes using the US dialect) due to the similarities between the countries; however, I have also seen it be considered French and Italian.

To answer your question for those suggestions:

- English - both
- Italian - gendered only (although 'loro' has recently been adopted for people who specifically wish to be ungendered)
- French - both

---

Copying a comment by user [indigochild](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/16058/indigochild) so it's not lost to time:

> An additional supporting detail: Lost Omens Legends contains writeups of several genderless/nonbinary/genderfluid characters. None of them contain any descriptions of pronouns. Paizo just uses whatever pronouns without comment.

Comment: +1. An additional supporting detail: Lost Omens Legends contains writeups of several genderless/nonbinary/genderfluid characters. None of them contain any descriptions of pronouns. Paizo just uses whatever pronouns without comment.

Comment: I haven't read Lost Omens Legends -- thank you.  This lack of detail does impact role play, because people who work in gendered languages tend to take note of people who don't, so I guess Wheaton's Law will decide this, as you suggest.